# npm execution stopped on windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a script to run `mocha` test cases defined in `package.json` as below:

```
...
'test':  mocha tests/integration/ --opts mocha.opts -t 20000
...
```

the test will be running about 10 minutes. This script works fine in Mac and Linux but not in Windows10.

When executing on windows10, the test cases are executing but after a few minutes the process gets stopped with below error messages:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "test:integration:win"
npm ERR! node v7.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3221225725
npm ERR! mycontroller@0.1.4 test:integration:win: `mocha tests/integration/ --opts mocha.opts -t 20000`
npm ERR! Exit status 3221225725
npm ERR!
```

This message has nothing to do with the test cases themselves. I believe they are related with environment. Does anyone know anything about this issue?

This is a `nodejs` backend application.

Comment: Are you using node-sass? Could be related to https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1863

Comment: No I am not using node-sass. it is a nodejs backend application.

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: I don't have any solution for that. Probably there is something wrong with windows process management.